# How to tell when my batch of EAP calls are completed?

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is following my question: [How to consume web service adheres to the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607038/c-how-to-consume-web-service-adheres-to-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern)

My program is calling the `DoStuffAsync()` **x** many times in a batch, hence the callback will get invoked the same number of times upon `OnComplete()`.

Is there a way to find out when my batch is finished such that I can generate a report on the success/failed results?

All I can think of is to have a static count variable for **x** and deduct 1 every time OnComplete() is called, but its kind of silly and error prone I'm afraid.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you already mentioned is the way to go. Maybe with a little more effort:

- Don't hard wire **x**. Increase it by one every time you call `DoStuffAsync()`.
- Don't make it static. Instead it is a private field of your class.
- If it is public static somewhere in the outer world take a look into [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)ing.